# Setting up git on a remote server

Tags: git, github, debian

I have a Debian 7 (Wheezy) (64-bit version) VPS up and running, I wanted to install git on it and use it as a remote repository.
To do that I followed this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-git-server-on-a-vps) and I think I got everything as it should be.

Now I have a project with some files in my local computer so I wanted to push them into a repository, I tried the following command: 
`git init && git remote add origin git@xx.xx.xx.xx:my-project.git`

The thing now, when I try to push something from my local computer with the command:
 `git push origin master`
and then entering the password for the git user I get the following error:

```
fatal: 'my-project.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: URL `git@xx.xx.xx.xx:my-project.git` means directory `my-project.git` in the home dir of user `git` at server xx.xx.xx.xx. Is it so no? Can you list the directory with `ssh git@xx.xx.xx.xx ls my-project.git`?

Comment: For your remote, did you set it as ```git@xx.xx.xx.xx:my-project.git``` or ```git@xx.xx.xx.xx:/path/on/server/to/my-project.git```?